# install location is adding extra path to installation directory

Tags: install4j

I have two screens for directory selection.
1. Installation Location screen : selects installation directory
2. Directory selection screen : selects database directory

When I am changing the installation directory by clink on browse button
which ever path i am selecting extra path(program files) is added.

for example I have selected path : "C://some path"
what actually shown in path : "C://some path/program files"

I have some changes in media files as shown below.

[image]

However for directory selection screen i am not having this issue.

How can i remove the extra path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration of the "Installation location" screen, deselect the "Suggest application directory" property.